# Submitting to a different journal after "Major Revisions"

Tags: publications, ethics

This feels a bit like a grey area to me.

A student of mine has submitted a paper to a journal and has received a "major revisions" response. Instead of doing the revisions she wants to submit to a different, higher-impact journal. Is that ethical?

I understand that it may not be the best idea in terms of probability of acceptance, etc, etc, but she's approached me specifically to ask about the *ethics* of it, and I don't have a ready answer for her.

Comment: It is totally unethical.

Comment: What were the requested revisions?  If they wanted her to e.g. revise to take account of someone else's work or to fix an invalidating flaw (that she agrees is an invalidating flaw), it seems unethical to try to publish a version of the paper that does not make these corrections.  But if the referee just asked her to make changes that she doesn't agree are necessary: what's the ethical problem?  Also, it seems to me that the impact factors of the journals involved are completely irrelevant: I'm not even sure why you mention it.

Comment: If she disagrees that the major revision is necessary, I don't see the problem. She should simply inform the journal she is withdrawing the submission, and submit the paper wherever else she pleases.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark, I mention it because it was her reason for wanting to look elsewhere

Comment: @TheChainsOfMarkov: You didn't answer my first question.  Until you do that, I (and Dan Romik) don't see what the issue is.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: My bad.  There are no damning revisions, no invalidating flaws. It really is a matter of impact factor / journal fit.

Comment: Depending on the nature of the requested revisions it's quite likely that the second journal's reviewers will request similar revisions and your student will have gotten nowhere.  If by some chance the paper ends up being reviewed by the same reviewer, your student could be virtually certain to get another rejection.  If the requested revisions are reasonably needed, then it's best to make the revisions before resubmitting, no matter where the paper is going to be sent.

Comment: @Brian: The OP asked to concentrate on ethical rather than strategic aspects, but: yes, I agree.  The author should think carefully about the revisions and decide whether they are critical, reasonable, or unreasonable.  In all but the last case, implementing them before she resubmits anywhere is a good idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Law is concerned with the actions; ethics is defined by the reasons and motivations behind those actions.

- **Unethical:** Dr X employs an original method to improve his publications. Instead of spending a lot of time on literature review, improvement of his arguments and proofreading the manuscript, he simply prepares a first unpolished draft and sends it to a mediocre journal. The journals asks two or three experts to peer-review the paper; they voluntary spend their time to read Dr X's manuscript, spot the problems and suggest the ways to improve it. Dr X's collects the feedback, uses (some of) it to improve the paper, and sends the manuscript to a better journal. After a few iterations, the paper is accepted in a high-rank journal. Dr X is listed as the author, although the work is largely done by his anonymous peers.
- **Ethical:** Dr Y has spent a lot of time on her experiments and manuscript, before sending it to a journal. She is a bit shy and she chose a mediocre journal because she was not sure that her work deserves to be published in a better one. Two of three reviewers responses are very positive; one reviewer clearly did not understood the paper and requested a lot of major changes. These changes are unlikely to improve the paper; the reviewer simply requires to compare Dr Y's method with his own weak results from far far ago to get fresh citations. The editor takes the reviewer's point and requests the major review. Dr Y performed the comparison, but it is clear that there is no academic benefit in publishing it - the reviewer's method is clearly outdated. Dr Y decided not to include this comparison in her manuscript and sends it to another journal.

Comment: In my experience, what makes a paper publishable in a better journal is that the community views the results as being more significant, not good (rather than unterrible) writing or a good (rather than mediocre) peer review.  If issues like these are poor enough to stop a journal from publishing a paper it would otherwise want to, it is much more likely to get referee comments like "Your writing is poor; please improve it and resubmit" rather than to have the referee tell Dr. X how to rewrite the paper.  Also these repeated issues would drastically slow down Dr. X's publication rate...

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Dr X's strategy can actually increase the publication rate - he spends less time on each paper and submits many papers in parallel. In many journals, referees would provide more specific remarks than a simple "your writing is poor".

Comment: ....so it will certainly be in Dr. X's best interests to make these kinds of changes himself if he can.  If he really can't, and he has one Hope-diamond-in-the-rough of a paper, that after much referee improvement gets published in a top journal: sounds OK to me.  He got the help he got no matter where the paper finally appears, right?  So that this is an ethical problem seems rather far-fetched to me.  Does it correspond to anything in your experience?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Dr X strategically prefers not to pull his weight polishing his papers. He relies on someone else doing this job for him. This saves him time to publish more papers and achieve better publication rate. I think this is unethical; but I am not a Professor of Ethics, so I may be wrong.

Comment: Dmitry, we all decide not to polish our papers as completely as would if time were no object.  Someone who wants to get away with unpolished papers would do much better to resubmit without making the changes at all, because if the work is basically solid some other journal will accept it.  (Gian-Carlo Rota has a story about this in his *Indiscrete Thoughts*.)  Waiting 4-30 months for someone else to tell you, perhaps, how to rewrite your paper is really not pulling a fast one.  And if someone does this multiple times at the same journal, how is that any different or better?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark We can agree to disagree on it.

Comment: Let me express my disagreement with your definition of law and ethics, Dmitry. Ethics is what is right and wrong, whereas Law is ethical opinions enforced by social power.

Comment: I'm with @Pete on this, for the most part. There may be a microscopic ethical issue here to the extent that people like Dr X actually exist and the strategies they employ actually work, but for the most part I think your story of Dr X is a fiction. Dr X's method is worse than unethical - it simply won't work, so out of pure self-interest even amoral people are extremely unlikely to employ such a strategy. In particular, the student in OP's question doesn't sound like she is driven by such a motivation. In any case +1 for a nicely written and creative answer.

Answer (score 11):

According your question, the fact that she doesn't want to make the revisions is also a factor for wanting to look elsewhere: otherwise, why wouldn't she make the revisions *and* resubmit elsewhere?  You make it sound like the "major revisions" are not actually so major, and that your student wants to use this mostly as an excuse to try to trade up.

This may not be advisable, but it seems to me that it is wholly ethical.  Your student submitted the paper to the journal in good faith.  If the journal had responded, "We will accept your paper for publication conditional on making the following changes" then if the changes are minor enough, one could reasonably argue that she is reneging on the spirit of the bargain.  However, by describing the revisions as *major*, the journal is indicating that the paper is *not* acceptable to them in anything close to its current form: they have in fact *rejected* the paper while inviting the submission of an improved form of it.  They certainly do not guarantee that they will publish the resubmission, so the transaction is complete.  The author can decide whether or not she wants to resubmit.

As I said in the comments, if the revisions ask for contain changes that objectively need to be made -- correcting issues of authorship, attribution, priority, or fixing what any reasonable party would agree to be an invalidating flaw -- then it would be unethical to resubmit elsewhere without making the changes.  But certainly the author can make exactly the changes requested and resubmit elsewhere.  Whether she resubmits to a better or worse journal makes no ethical difference whatsoever.

Comment: It's interesting that you and @Dmitry-Savostyanov make different recommendations with respect to the revisions themselves.  You suggest making the revisions and moving on to a separate journal, whereas he says that that strategy—taken to a logical conclusion—is unethical.  Out of curiosity, why do you suggest she make the revisions?  Also, you do make a fine distinction about the "majorness" of the revisions.  "Major revisions" is literally what the journal's letter said; on whom does the responsibility lie to determine what's "major enough"?

Comment: @TheChainsOfMarkov: "You suggest making the revisions and moving on to a separate journal" No, that's not what I said.  I gave specific conditions under which the author should make the revisions; absent them, she certainly can choose whether she wants to make them, and from the story it sounds to me like an absence of a desire to make the revisions is probably a factor in her decision (although you seem to downplay this).

Comment: Downplayed only because it would be speculation on my part.  I haven't asked her specifically about this, but I will.

Comment: As for "majorness" of revisions: I thought I explained that in my answer.  Yes, "Major Revisions" is literally what they said, so they (the editors, as advised by the referees) decided that.  Major Revisions means "We do not accept your paper as yet."  "Accepted with minor revisions" means what it sounds like.